# Visual mode on Windows GVIM not working as expected

Tags: vim, gvim

I've just installed last version of GVIM and I have problem with Visual mode - when I enter Visual mode it has just normal edit mode cursor, in status line Visual mode is marked as active but, moving cursor doesn't selects text at all.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your font/colors are broken.

(From normal mode) does

```
Vjjjd
```

Delete 3 rows of text?

EDIT: Definitely broken colors. Try without [g]vimrc

Comment: Yes thats, what is happening right now.

Comment: Ok, can you try without a .gvimrc ? What platform are you on. Your colorscheme is broken.